# Windows Credential Provider - Is there a way to communicate or interfere with windows Hello API?

Tags: windows, credential-providers, windows-hello

I am developing the credential provider, that require to communicate / interfere with windows hello and get the authentication done.

Is there any way to communicate with Windows Hello and alter the functionality of authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is not very clear. Windows Hello and Windows Biometric Credential Provider communicate with Windows Biometric Framework API and this WBF API requires a compatible driver that implements Windows Biometric Driver Interface.

If you are developing a credential provider with a propietary driver this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45878192/403999