# Is it possible to bypass the Password to Login To Window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, credential-providers

I am developing a custom Windows Credential Provider for Local PC

The Idea is we want to make a passwordless Credential Provider.

From user prespective, they will just

1. Select the desired username that you want to login with
2. There will be 2nd factor authentication by Mobile Phone App
3. If the User accept or confirm the authentication, Window will log the user in with the selected username

Currently my Credential Provider works as follows:

1. I Create an executable to manage the password and the Username of desired Windows Account
2. Everytime the user register their password and username, it will be saved somewhere in local PC  (eg: C:\Temp\MyCredential\identity.txt). Since it I have no plan to join the PC with a domain, the domain value that saved in the database is their own's pc name
3. When the user perform authentication and confirm it, The provider will take the domain, username, and password information from the file in step 2
4. From the step 3, I feed / put the value to `KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON` like this

```
HRESULT CMyCredential::GetSerialization(
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE* pcpgsr,
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION* pcpcs,
    PWSTR* ppwszOptionalStatusText,
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON* pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon
)
{
...
 KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON kiul;

hr = KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonInit((PWSTR)wdomain.c_str(), (PWSTR)wusername.c_str(), (PWSTR)pwd.c_str(), _cpus, &kiul);
...
}
```

--------- QUESTION ------------------

Then something just comes up to our mind.

If the user change their password using Windows settings `Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options -> change password`, how do we let the user log in?

So far we thought that its impossible since we use the txt file which is not synchronized with the Windows password

But after do a quick search, I found [Credential Provider in Windows for Bio-metric Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631222/credential-provider-in-windows-for-bio-metric-authentication) which explain that I have to create SSP/AP to make my Credential Provider able to do that mechanism https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375200(v=vs.85).aspx

Is it possible, or is it impossible?

Comment: To logon this way you'll need to implement SSP/AP on both sides - domain controller(s) and local workstation. Certificate logon act's this way.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for your insight. By the way, I am planning to do this on local pc. Therefore no domain controller(s) involved. Do you have any example how to utilize SSP/AP for the local pc?

Comment: In your scenario you will have a domain controller of your own workstation. Everry Windows computer hold's it's own local domain. For this scenario there are no difference's.

Comment: Ah so local computer has its own domain controller. And what about the custom SSP/AP. Do you have any project example how to create it?